# Distinct particular field in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have table with below sample values.

```
|Id|Keyword|insertedon|
|:-|:------|:---------|
|1 | abcd  | 13/12/20 |
|2 | cdef  | 14/12/20 |
|3 | abcd  | 14/12/20 |
|4 | defg  | 14/12/20 |
```

In the above table i need distinct values of keywords order by insertedon desc order.
I need recent top 5 results.
Expected Result:

```
defc
abcd
cdef
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Should abcd be sorted after its first or last insertedon value?

Comment: I need recent top 5 distinct values,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the top 5 results with `TOP(5)` in SQL Server. You'd order the keywords by their last `insertedon` date:

```
select top(5) keyword
from mytable
group by keyword
order by max(insertedon) desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for latest entries based on insertedon column, you can find using the group by clause, something like this:

```
select keyword, max(insertedon)
from table
group by keyword
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct keyword
from t;
```

If you wanted a full row, you could use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by keyword order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

For the edited version, you can use:

```
select distinct keyword
from (select top (5) keyword
      from t
      order by insertedon desc
     ) k
```

Comment: I need recent top 5 results.

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number based on the descending order of the date column and then select the row wth row number 1.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
  select [rn] = row_number() over(
    partition by [keyword]
    order by [insertedon] desc, [id] desc
  )
)
select [keyword] from cte
where [rn] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical functions as follows:

```
select t.* from 
   (select t.*,
           row_number() over (partition by keyword order by insertedon desc) as rn,
           Dense_rank() over (order by insertedon desc) as dr
      from t ) t where rn = 1 and dr <= 5;
```